# Change default value of column to expression

Tags: mariadb, default

I'm trying to alter an existing columns default value from 'no default value at all' to 'tomorrow's date' on the DBMS-side.

---

More specific:

By inserting a data-row into my table, I wanna have by default the date of tomorrow in a column (at timestamp of the insert).

Used tools:

- MariaDB v15.1 for debian-linux-gnu (I'm using the CLI 'MariaDB
  monitor' for my operations)
- Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) as a virtual server in data-center
- putty v0.65 with UTF-8 transmission

---

My **general SQL-command** for initiate altering of my column is:

```
ALTER TABLE test
    CHANGE COLUMN tomorrow
        tomorrow date not null default (EVIL-EXPRESSION);
```

---

**'EVIL-EXPRESSION'** in the code-sample above is just a placeholder for following **possibilities**:

```
default (date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day))
```

or

```
default (adddate(current_date(), 1))
```

or

```
default (now() + interval 1 day)
```

or

```
default (today + interval 1 day)
# today is a column declared before actual column 'tomorrow'
```

---

And some other variations/alias with the same error code result:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version
for the right syntax to use near '(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day))'
at line 1
```

Due to goolge this error number '1064 (42000)' indicates a parenthesis mismatch. I'm pretty sure, that this is not the case here. And when it is, then I need definitely holidays. ;)

---

Due to the [official MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#default), expressions are allowed in the default statement since version 10.2+.

Also [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/mariadb-102-check-and-default-clauses) enthuses this feature - with a not working example for me (with the 'alter table'-statement). Scroll down until **"The DEFAULT Clause"** section.

Even evil characters can't be blamed for my error like [this genius pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36527137/1542878).

---

Maybe a bug of MariaDB?

And sure, I can and actually do a workaround on the server-site PHP script without any default value. But I'm still interested to outsource it to the database for more comfort - one-stop-service. ;)

I'm thankful for every input, so let the brainstorming begin - since my brain is smoking. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [CREATE TABLE::DEFAULT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#default). Verify your version of MariaDB.

Test:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 10.3.8-MariaDB-1:10.3.8 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    ->   `id` SERIAL,
    ->   `today` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    ->   `tomorrow` DATE
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DESC `test`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Field: id
   Type: bigint(20) unsigned
   Null: NO
    Key: PRI
Default: NULL
  Extra: auto_increment
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Field: today
   Type: date
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: curdate()
  Extra: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Field: tomorrow
   Type: date
   Null: YES
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [_]> ALTER TABLE `test`
    ->   CHANGE COLUMN `tomorrow`
    ->   `tomorrow` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (`today` + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.004 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [_]> DESC `test`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Field: id
   Type: bigint(20) unsigned
   Null: NO
    Key: PRI
Default: NULL
  Extra: auto_increment
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Field: today
   Type: date
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: curdate()
  Extra: 
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Field: tomorrow
   Type: date
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: (`today` + interval 1 day)
  Extra: 
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) SELECT NULL;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [_]> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `today`,
    ->   `tomorrow`
    -> FROM
    ->   `test`;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | today      | tomorrow   |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-02 |
+----+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: Yes! My version of MariaDB was 10.1.26 (or similar). Seems like I have read the wrong version name from "mariadb --version"-output. Installed MariaDB 10.3.8 and now it's working fine. Thx @wchiquito!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is your Error: and you are missing a paranthesys:

```
default (adddate(current_date(), 1)
```

Count them: you open 3 and close only 2 !!!!

Comment: Thx Simion, yeah, you're right. In my post above there are plenty of them. But on my server they are not - lack of concentration meanwhile.

To be 100% sure I just tried some possibilities with extra concentration on parenthesis and still same error.

Will fix my post.